# How to count how many customers had a specific event in SQL

Tags: sql, count

I'm trying to count how many customers have 1 or more swiped transaction in 2019. The query I've written below keeps returning the number of total swiped transactions, not the number of customers with a swiped transaction. What do I need to change in order to have the count show the number of customers, not the number of transactions?

```
select count(c.id)
from customers c
left join transactions t on t.customer_id = c.id 
where t.is_swipe = 'Y'
and t.created_date between '2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31' 
and t.is_swipe > 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT` :

```
select count(distinct c.id)
from customers c inner join 
     transactions t on t.customer_id = c.id 
where t.is_swipe = 'Y' and 
      t.created_date between '2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31' and 
      t.is_swipe > 0;
```

You can use `INNER JOIN` to check only swiped transaction customer instead of `LEFT JOIN`.

However, you can also use `exists` :

```
select count(c.id)
from customers c 
where exists (select 1 
              from transactions t 
              where t.created_date between '2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31' and 
                    t.is_swipe > 0 and
                    t.customer_id = c.id
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT <column>)`. For example:

```
select count(distinct c.id)
from customers c
left join transactions t on t.customer_id = c.id 
where t.is_swipe = 'Y'
and t.created_date between '2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31' 
and t.is_swipe > 0
```

However, it's unclear to me if the column `t.is_swipe` is numeric of varchar. You are comparing it twice against different values.